# If statement passes only when preceded by debug cout line (multi-threading in C)

Tags: c++, multithreading

I created this code to use for solving CPU intensive tasks real-time and potentially as a base for a game engine in the future. For it I created a system where there is an array of ints each thread modifies to signal whether they are done with their current task.

The problem occurs when running it with more than 4 threads. When using 6 threads or more, the **"if (threadone_private == threadcount)"** stops working UNLESS I add this debug line **"cout << threadone_private << endl;"** before it.

I cannot comprehend why this debug line makes any difference on whether the if conditional functions as expected, neither why it works without it when using 4 threads or less.

For this code I'm using:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
```

Right now this code only counts up to 60 trillion, in asynchronous steps of 3 billion, really fast.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
int thread_done[6] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };
atomic<long long int> testvar1 = 0;
atomic<long long int> testvar2 = 0;
atomic<long long int> testvar3 = 0;
atomic<long long int> testvar4 = 0;
atomic<long long int> testvar5 = 0;
atomic<long long int> testvar6 = 0;

void task1(long long int testvar, int thread_number)
{
    int continue_work = 1;
    for (; ; ) {
        while (continue_work == 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 3000000001; i++) {
                testvar++;
            }
            thread_done[thread_number] = 1;
            if (thread_number==0) {
                testvar1 = testvar;
            }
            if (thread_number == 1) {
                testvar2 = testvar;
            }
            if (thread_number == 2) {
                testvar3 = testvar;
            }
            if (thread_number == 3) {
                testvar4 = testvar;
            }
            if (thread_number == 4) {
                testvar5 = testvar;
            }
            if (thread_number == 5) {
                testvar6 = testvar;
            }
            continue_work = 0;
        }
        if (thread_done[thread_number] == 0) {
            continue_work = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant part of the main thread:

```
int main() {
    long long int testvar = 0;
    int threadcount = 6;
    int threadone_private = 0;
    thread thread_1(task1, testvar, 0);
    thread thread_2(task1, testvar, 1);
    thread thread_3(task1, testvar, 2);
    thread thread_4(task1, testvar, 3);
    thread thread_5(task1, testvar, 4);
    thread thread_6(task1, testvar, 5);
    for (; ; ) {
        if (threadcount == 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 3000001; i++) {
                testvar++;
            }
            cout << testvar << endl;
        }
        else {
            while (testvar < 60000000000000) {
                threadone_private = thread_done[0] + thread_done[1] + thread_done[2] + thread_done[3] + thread_done[4] + thread_done[5];
                cout << threadone_private << endl;
                if (threadone_private == threadcount) {
                    testvar = testvar1 + testvar2 + testvar3 + testvar4 + testvar5 + testvar6;
                    cout << testvar << endl;
                    thread_done[0] = 0;
                    thread_done[1] = 0;
                    thread_done[2] = 0;
                    thread_done[3] = 0;
                    thread_done[4] = 0;
                    thread_done[5] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that since each worker thread only modifies one int out of the array threadone_private, and since the main thread only ever reads it until all worker threads are waiting, that this if (threadone_private == threadcount) should be bulletproof... Apparently I'm missing something important that goes wrong whenever I change this:

```
                threadone_private = thread_done[0] + thread_done[1] + thread_done[2] + thread_done[3] + thread_done[4] + thread_done[5];
                cout << threadone_private << endl;
                if (threadone_private == threadcount) {
```

To this:

```
threadone_private = thread_done[0] + thread_done[1] + thread_done[2] + thread_done[3] + thread_done[4] + thread_done[5];
//cout << threadone_private << endl;
                if (threadone_private == threadcount) {
```

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with threads, but `thread_done` is not atomic, so maybe you're experiencing a race condition?

Comment: `I cannot comprehend why this debug line makes any difference on whether the if conditional functions as expected` could be a timing thing. That debug statement will take time to execute, changing the timing of everything.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Chipster .

I considered that it could be a race condition, specially since I did this mistake a couple times in this code before. But this time it doesn't seem like it should be the case since it works 100% with 4 threads or the comment, but fails 100% of times in the absence of both.

Else, as far as I understand it couldn't be a race condition case if the main thread is never writing back to the array, just reading it until conditions are true. But I may be wrong as I'm actually just starting to learn about C++.

Any idea on how I could test for it?

Comment: Yeah, like I say, I'm not too experienced with threads. But, I think in C++ there are certain conditions where a race condition only requires one writer. But I can't find the link off hand, so I may be making it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Concurrent code is quite complicated and easy to get wrong, so it's generally a good idea to use higher level abstractions. There are a whole lot of details that are easy to get wrong without ever noticing. You should think very carefully about doing such low-level programming if you're not an expert. Sadly C++ lacks good built-in high level concurrent constructs, but there are libraries out there that handle this.

It's unclear what the whole code is supposed to do anyhow to me. As far as I can see whether the code ever stops relies purely on timing - even if you did the synchronization correctly - which is completely non deterministic. Your threads could execute in such a way that `thread_done` is never all true.

But apart from that there is at least one correctness issue: You're reading and writing to `int thread_done[6] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };` without synchronization. This is undefined behavior so the compiler can do what it wants.

What probably happens is that the compiler sees that it can cache the value of `threadone_private` since the thread never writes to it so the value cannot change (legally). The external call to `std::cout` means it can't be sure that the value isn't change behind its back so it has to read the value each iteration new (also std::cout uses locks which causes synchronization in most implementations which again limits what the compiler can assume).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply, I would give you reputation if I already had the 15 required for me to do so. I am indeed new to C++, and it's probably a bad idea to jump from Python and JavaScript right into such a low level language, but I got to say I'm in love with the speed of it and I found out my masters degree will require me to use it.

I will try to follow your advice and give abstractions in the future together with only smaller snippets of code. Else I will keep in mind how the compiler may decide to cache variables and find ways to force it to treat them as desired. :)

Comment: @Anderson No worries about the rep. But still I think you're trying to reimplement some probably well known pattern. You might want to ask a question explaining what you're actually trying to do, because the semantics of the current code are confusing. I'd think your goal would be for the threads to stop when the shared counter reaches a specific point, but the given code isn't doing that reliably. Using a thread pool and some condition variables would be preferable.

Comment: Actually yes. But what I really would like to achieve is not for threads to do a job and die, but rather keep working at a job continuously(asynchronously) and periodically copy their private variable into a public variable that other threads can only read. Only because in that way I believe I can get around idle time and get the threads to work non stop. But I still need to be able to have them signal that said public variable is safe for reading by other threads. But I'm really wondering whether this would be that much faster for most tasks than just a thread pool. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: So, was I correct when I said "race condition"? Because that would be awesome if I actually got it right...

Answer (score -1):

I cannot see any std::mutex, std::condition_variable or variants of std::lock in your code. Doing multithreading without any of those will never succeed reliably. Because whenever multiple threads modify the same data, you need to make sure only one thread (including your main thread) has access to that data at any given time.

Edit: I noticed you use atomic. I do not have any experience with this, however I know using mutexes works reliably.

Therefore, you need to lock every access (read or write) to that data with a mutex like this:

```
//somewhere
std::mutex myMutex;
std::condition_variable myCondition;
int workersDone = 0;

/* main thread */

createWorkerThread1();
createWorkerThread2();

{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex); //waits until mutex is locked.
    while(workersDone != 2) {
        myCondition.wait(lock); //the mutex is unlocked while waiting
    }
    std::cout << "the data is ready now" << std::endl;
} //the lock is destroyed, unlocking the mutex

/* Worker thread */

while(true) {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex); //waits until mutex is locked

        if(read_or_modify_a_piece_of_shared_data() == DATA_FINISHED) {
            break; //lock leaves the scope, unlocks the mutex
        }
    }

    prepare_everything_for_the_next_piece_of_shared_data(); //DO NOT access data here
}

//data is processed
++workersDone;
myCondition.notify_one(); //no mutex here. This wakes up the waiting thread
```

I hope this gives you an idea on how to use mutexes and condition variables to gain thread safety.

Disclaimer: 100% pseudo code ;)

Comment: "Doing multithreading without any of those will never succeed reliably" huh? No you don't have to lock for concurrent code to work correctly. Even worse, you really can't judge concurrent code by simply looking at what calls are being made. For example creating a thread will include synchronization points out of the box and so on.

Comment: I forgot about the existence of atomics, but I am pretty sure that without using techniques that ensure only one thread can access shared data - which is not the case when using std::thread alone - the code will mess up sooner or later (sooner most of the time).

Comment: Quite so, but there are atomic variables and you can do multi threading without writing to shared data. And you definitely can't say  "I don't see X,Y,Z ergo this must be wrong", because as the example with thread creation shows there are other calls that  give you synchronization points.

Comment: OP. however, is using shared Data - my Statement was maybe misleading/wrong, but this question is about a race condition, after all a line of cout changes the outcome - this would not happen if the code was thread safe.

Comment: Oh yes in this case the missing synchronization is quite obvious (apart from the logical problem in the code) and if you simply talked about that the answer would be correct. But I could for example write perfectly valid code that does not use any explicit locks or even atomic variables and still synchronizes correctly, so focusing too much on specific tools instead of the actual issue is dangerous in something is complex as concurrent code.

Comment: Well, in that case I am not aware that this is possible.